# MS Project On-line

Tags: ms-project

Is there any on-line ms project like software which allow create project plans and save it in Microsoft Project format? I know  [www.amiproject.com](http://www.amiproject.com), but it let just view plans.

Comment: Just a point of terminology: a _project plan_ is not the same thing as a **gantt chart**.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Gantter](http://gantter.com/)

It features MPP import and XML export

Comment: Gantter is also free and does not need you to register to try out and download the plans that you create with it in XML or MPP format which is good. Seems to have an elegant user interface and seems to be fairly responsive.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Tom's Planner](http://www.tomsplanner.com/) in the past and got on really well with it. Very easy to use and has all the things I needed such as dependencies, sub-tasks and collaboration, presented in Gantt style.

They're also quite responsive to queries on [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com/tomsplanner).

It doesn't save in MPP format but it does export an XML, XLS or CSV file which enables you to import into MS Project.

Answer (score 1):

I listend to a recent podcast of the [PMO Podcast](http://www.botinternational.com/thepmopodcast.htm), where Mark Perry interviewed an expert on MS Project 2010. I'm pretty sure they said that with the integration fully into SharePoint it could now be a cloud use product. You'd probably want to listen to the podcast to be sure.